# Intermittent problems saving Libreoffice documents to samba share

Tags: 20.04, samba, libreoffice

When editing Libreoffice documents that reside on a samba share, most saves work as expected. But occasionally the save will fail and the following window will pop up (for example):

[image]

This was taken from a test where I saved the same document four times successfully without exiting the document, then it failed on the fifth try.

If the document is exited and then reopening it is attempted through double clicking in `caja`, this box is displayed:

[image]

Clued in by this, I found that there was a hidden file in the remote directory called (in this case) `.~lock.HEBGroceryList.odt#`

Deleting this file allows the document to be edited again.

This is frustrating, but even worse is that it all started after upgrading our systems to 20.04. I had this all set up and working perfectly on our 18.04 systems for years.

So much changed in the upgrade to 20.04 that I don't have any idea where to start looking for workarounds or fixes. However, since the samba shares work perfectly in all other applications - copying files, backing up the systems, playing audio and video - I am inclined to suspect that this is a Libreoffice problem.

Additional info: the samba shares are mounted through fstab using lines like:

```
//192.168.1.2/[sharename] /media/[mountpoint] cifs vers=3.0,credentials=[credential-file],iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=[username],gid=[username],nofail 0 0
```

How can I regain the ability to save Libreoffice documents consistently on samba shares in 20.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried to add the `nobrl` option to your list:

```
//192.168.1.2/[sharename] /media/[mountpoint] cifs vers=3.0,credentials=[credential-file],iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=[username],gid=[username],nofail,nobrl 0 0
```

Comment: No, I was unaware of that option. Will give it a try.

Comment: Preliminary testing indicates that this worked, so I'm accepting your answer. Will report back if anything comes up during normal usage. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this is the old issue with `gvfs`. Here's something you can try:

1. Edit one of the LibreOffice `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` using your text editor of choice
2. Find the line that reads `X-GIO-NoFuse=true` and comment it out
3. Open that application as you normally would

If you are able to properly save, then you can make the same edit to all of the other LibreOffice `.desktop` files in the same directory

Comment: Thanks for your post. I should definitely have mentioned that the shares are mounted with fstab. Apologies for leaving out that important fact, I will edit the question, and have an upvote. I will try this!